# DateTimePicker not going off after selecting the date from the widget

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<br/>
<!-- padding for jsfiddle -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    <h6>datetimepicker1</h6>
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
    <span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span>
    </span>
    </div>
    </div>
    <h6>datetimepicker2</h6>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datetimepicker2" />
    </div>
</div>

    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
    $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker();
```

The Problem I am facing is that, once I open the widget and select it, it is not closing but if I click on the body it will close.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Eonasdan/0Ltv25o8/ This is the JS Fiddle I have used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work around by subscribe event 'dp.change' to close it:

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker()
    .on('dp.change', function(){
        $('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").hide();
    });
$('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker()
    .on('dp.change', function(){
        $('#datetimepicker2').data("DateTimePicker").hide();
        $('#datetimepicker2').blur(); // blur its focus
    });
```

Refer: https://jsfiddle.net/hungndv/0Ltv25o8/1439/

Comment: Its Working Thanks for an answer but when we click it again its not showing up when the textbox is active.. Why is it so?

Comment: I update the solution with your request. Let try. :D